# Symfony2 relationship between 3 entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been stuck on this for couple of days. I'm building a voting plugin, where users vote for candidates in districts, and the candidates belong to age range. Each district has a defined number of seats.

So i have the **Districts entity**, and the **Age Range entity**, (of course the candidates entity too).

So when I create the districts, I have to add a number of seats. Each seat belongs to an Age Range. Example:

Districts 1 has 5 seats.
Seat1 belongs to Range1
Seat2 belongs to Range2
Seat3 belongs to Range1
Seat4 belongs to Range1
Seat5 belongs to Range3

I tried a many to many relationship between the districts and the age ranges, of course it created a bridge table, but the thing is, i can't add multiple seats for the same Range!

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,

Emma

Answer (score 0):

How About having:

- A **District** entity
- A **Seat** entity
- A **Age Range** entity

So each district will be associated to a number of seats with a ManyToOne relationship and each seat will be associated to an Age Range with a ManyToOne relationship.

That way you could have multiple seats for the same age range.

Comment: I tried so, but how to set that in form?

let's say i have 5 seats, i'd display 5 drop down menus of the Age Range lists, and select from them. How can that happen?